# sheep's opinion or opinion of the sheep

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

This is a famous game of thrones quote:

> The lion does not concern himself with the opinion of the sheep.

what is the difference between this sentence and this sentence:

> The lion does not concern himself with the sheep's opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. You can use **of the..** or **'s** for people, organisations and animals:

The sister of my friend / My friend's sister

The headquarters of the company / The company's headquarters

What's the name of the dog / the dog's name

Use **... of the** for things:

.. the temperature of the water, the name of the painting, the number of the house

Use **'s** for times:

Next week's meeting, 5-days' holiday

Answer (score 3):

When discussing possession or attribution, there is no difference between using "of the" and the possessive (apostrophe + s). The sheep's opinion and the opinion of the sheep are the same thing. The car's colour and the colour of the car likewise. So are the queen's coat and the coat of the queen. This is true for people, animals, and inanimate objects.

> Possessives of inanimate objects: Despite rumors to the contrary, an
>   inanimate object can form a possessive. The car’s engine is
>   overheating. The laptop’s hard drive is fried.

[The apostrophe](http://thewritingresource.net/2010/08/26/the-apostrophe-beyond-the-basics/)

> there’s no difference between the speed of the vehicle and the
>   vehicle’s speed (or “vehicle speed,”

[Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/PossessivesandAttributives.html?page=2)

Comment: I'd disagree about the car's colour, Michael.

Comment: In what way do you disagree?

Comment: Michael, I'd say it isn't common spoken style to use 's genitive with objects. I'd probably make a compound noun. Where are the car keys? What the house number, what's the water temperature There's something wrong with the computer hard drive.